# Spring + Hibernate application not releasing memory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, memory

We have created a spring web app. using:

- Spring 3.1.0
- Hibernate 3.5.4 final
- tomcat 6.24

The application is reasonably heavy, we are sending about 1000 contacts per user request.
We tested our application with 9 concurrent users with repeated requests and profiled with visual vm the results are as follows:

[image]

Looking at the results, the high peaks are the repeated requests and the lower points are when all requests are stopped. The first ~200MB of memory does not seem to be released at all. Is spring actually just this heavy or do I have a potential memory issue? The release version of this web app will potentially handle much more users.

I have similar results testing on tomcat 7 as well.

Comment: how many cpu cores you have? and what is hardware and tomcat configuration regarding to memory

Comment: I am testing on an iMac core i7 with 4 cores, 16GB memory and tomcat configured to have -Xms512M -Xmx1024M, although the production server we have to use has less memory, the settings are the same with the potential for 2GB if needed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what UI is that?

Comment: @danielbeard Did you ever find an answer?  I'm having a similar issue with Hibernate and Glassfish.

Comment: @dacracot have long since moved on from working on Spring stuff, so unfortunately don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not any memory issue, GC is smart enough that release objects after there is no reference in your application, make sure that there is no global reference for which can be used as local to any method, and as per your graph it is releasing objects, 200 mb may be required tor permgen, so you should not worry.